# Does Firefox Sync also sync cookies?

Tags: firefox, cookies, firefox-sync

Does *Firefox Sync* also sync cookies?

Which one of the [many options](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-do-i-choose-what-types-information-sync-firefox) activates this:  Open Tabs, Bookmarks, Logins, History, Add-ons, or Preferences?

Comment: None, of those options, would sync cookies.

Comment: @Ramhound "None, of those options, would sync cookies." --- So sync does not sync cookies? (This is what I want to know.)

Comment: "Which of the many options† activates this?" - The options you listed would not include cookies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the official answer is "no."

There is a long-standing [Bugzilla report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=638865) asking them to enable this capability.  Based upon the subsequent discussions within that page, trying to sync cookies would be problematic:

> **Richard Newman [:rnewman]**
>   It could be done, but I doubt we'd want to support it.

> **alex**
>   why not? would be useful for many people. when its a problem with storage space on mozilla servers ... it would okay when its only supported on own sync-servers.

> **Richard Newman [:rnewman]**
>   Nothing to do with space, and everything to do with potentially destroying your browsing experience. I have little confidence in being able to reconcile simultaneous changes to your Facebook session cookie, for example. That means data loss.

> **Gregory Szorc [:gps]**
>   Cookie sync is not currently on the roadmap.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome has a great plugin for this, [SyncMyCookie](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/syncmycookie/laapobniolmbhnkldepjnebendehhmmf), maybe work with [Chrome Store Foxified](https://github.com/Noitidart/Chrome-Store-Foxified/).

UPDATE: Seems worked fine to me, but I had to follow the plugin instructions to install unsigned extensions.

Answer (score 0):

probably has to do with security/privacy issues...
if someone know's a third party website/tool to export/sync cookies, let it now...

for firefox i'm  trying  "EXP Cookies" looks good so far...

André